# How to replicate models with nested relations in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.1

I have a model with a lot of nested relations. I first load them like this:

```
<?php
$model = Model::where('id', $id)
    ->with(
        'relation1',
        'relation2',
        'relation2.subrelation1', 
        'relation2.subrelation2',
        'relation3', 
        'relation3.subrelation1', 
        'relation3.subrelation2',
        'relation3.subrelation3', 
        'relation3.subrelation4.subrelation', 
    )->get();
?>
```

And here is how I replicate the relations and eventually clone them.

```
<?php
$clone = $model->replicate();
$clone->push();

foreach ($model->getRelations() as $relation => $entries){
    foreach($entries as $entry){
        $e = $entry->replicate();
            if ($e->push()){
                $clone->{$relation}()->save($e);

                // @todo Go further down
            }
        }
    }
}
?>
```

The problem is that this works perfectly for relations in the first level; however, if there are additional nested relations, they are not getting replicated/cloned. What is the most efficient way to traverse further in the relations and replicate them all?

Thanks

Answer (score 8):

I would overwrite the `replicate()` method on your models to also replicate the children.  Then I would extract that functionality into a trait, and apply the trait to all of your models.  Something like:

```
trait DeepReplicates {
    public function replicate(){
        $copy = parent::replicate();
        $copy->push();

        foreach ($model->getRelations() as $relation => $entries){
            foreach($entries as $entry){
                $e = $entry->replicate();
                if ($e->push()){
                    $clone->{$relation}()->save($e);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then apply that trait, and every model that gets replicated will also replicate its' own children, recursively down the line.  You have to make sure you don't end up in a loop, but it should work.

You could even add a variable to each model to specify an array of the child models that should be replicated.  That would avoid a possible logic loop.

Comment: Do you mind showing me what the replicate function inside the model would look like?

Comment: The one you could write is in my answer.  The existing one is in your source code in Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model, API here: https://laravel.com/api/5.3/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method_replicate

Comment: This will work but is very slow if you have a lot of records.

Comment: Hi @Jeff. Would this work for let's say I have a `Lesson` model, then it has a child `Quiz` then the `Quiz` model has a child `MultipleChoice`, `TrueFalse`, and `FillBlank` models. Would this work for this kind of scenario?